# .net maui custom control handlers, how to convert Content between virtualview and platformview

Tags: .net, maui, maui-windows

I am trying to create a custom Maui Handler for WinUI3 NavigationView.

I have defined the mapping from the virtualView to the PlatformView but i cant seem to convert the Virtual view Content to the PlatformView Content,

An example would be I have a NavigationView.Content = Microsoft.Maui.Frame.Content.

Looking through the maui code there seems to be some mappers but i cant figure out how to get these invoked.

Here is my current code

```
public static void MapContent(IZtNavigationViewHandler viewHandler, IZtNavigationView virtualView) 
{ 
  ((NavigationView)(viewHandler?.PlatformView)).Content = virtualView.Content; 
}
```

The mapper is being called but it cant convert the content correctly

Any Ideas or pointers?

Comment: What is your long-range goal? WinUI3’s NavigationView is specific to Windows. Maui’s strength is cross-platform. If you plan on supporting platforms other than Windows, it would be better to build up functionality similar to NavigationView, using Maui’s cross-platform views. Starting with NavigationPage or AppShell. What you are attempting is an advanced topic. Not yet well-documented (nor robust yet - I’ve encountered crashes today, attempting to use Navigationview as a PlatformView).

Comment: Yeah i know, Maui falls short with shell for complex application navigation.  the single level menu structure wont work for me.  Also i wanted to implement the iOS navview so that on the ipad/macos it would have a more native look.  And in addition i need to implement the winui3 TabView and a simular approach.  lots to do but its needed for our app.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**
The lines in a hand-written custom handler’s mapper method, where Content is mapped:

```cs
    if (handler.VirtualView.PresentedContent is IView view) 
        handler.PlatformView.Children.Add(view.ToPlatform(handler.MauiContext));
```

OR if PlatformView has a Content property (NavigationView does), then:

```cs
    if (handler.VirtualView.PresentedContent is IView view) 
        handler.PlatformView.Content = view.ToPlatform(handler.MauiContext);
```

Approach 3 would use that syntax.

---

First, `Frame`, `ListView`, and `TableView` are ["legacy" Renderer-based views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize#renderer-based-views). They don't use handlers.

Don't use one of those.

Try `ContentView` as the virtual view.
In Maui source, `ContentViewHandler.Windows.cs` is the default behavior.

---

Given:

```cs
public class MyContentView : ContentView
{
}
```

Goal is to make a handler that maps MyContentView to WinUI3's NavigationView,
and MyContentView.Content to NavigationView.Content.

---

**ALTERNATIVE 1 - MyContentViewHandler**

Similar to [Customize specific control instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize#customize-specific-control-instances),
and similar to Maui source solution 'Microsoft.Maui' /
Controls / samples / Maui.Controls.Sample / Controls / BordelessEntry /
BordelessEntryHandler.cs.

One significant difference: Instead of mapping **directly** to a NavigationView, let MyContentView create ContentPanel (logic inherited from ContentViewHandler), then make NavigationView the child of ContentPanel.

```cs
using Microsoft.Maui;
using Microsoft.Maui.Handlers;
...
public class MyContentViewHandler : ContentViewHandler
{
    public static IPropertyMapper<IContentView, IContentViewHandler> Mapper =
        new PropertyMapper<IContentView, IContentViewHandler>(ViewMapper)
        {
            [nameof(IContentView.Content)] = MapContent,
        };
            
    public static void MapContent(IContentViewHandler handler, IContentView page)
    {
        UpdateContent(handler);
    }

    static void UpdateContent(IContentViewHandler handler)
    {
        _ = handler.PlatformView ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(PlatformView)} should have been set by base class.");
        _ = handler.VirtualView ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(VirtualView)} should have been set by base class.");
        _ = handler.MauiContext ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(MauiContext)} should have been set by base class.");

        handler.PlatformView.Children.Clear();

        if (handler.VirtualView.PresentedContent is IView view)
        {
            // platform equivalent to Content.
            var platformContent = view.ToPlatform(handler.MauiContext);
    #if WINDOWS
            // Wrap content in a NavigationView.
            var navView = new NavigationView();
            navView.Content = platformContent;
            handler.PlatformView.Children.Add(navView);
    #else
            handler.PlatformView.Children.Add(platformContent);
    #endif
        }
    }
}
```

---

**ALTERNATIVE 2 - Mapper.AppendToMapping**

INCOMPLETE ... not sure how/where to do this ...

Technique: AFTER standard mapping is performed, "fix up" MyContentView.

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(
    "MyContentViewAsNavView", (handler, view) =>
    {
        if (view is MyContentView)
        {
    #if WINDOWS
            if (handler.PlatformView.Children.Count > 0) {
                // ASSUME first child is the Content to wrap.
                var platformContent = handler.PlatformView.Children[0];
                // Wrap content in a NavigationView.
                var navView = new NavigationView();
                navView.Content = platformContent;
                handler.PlatformView.Children[0] = navView;
            }
    #endif
        }
    });
```

---

**ALTERNATIVE 3 - "NavigationPanel" adapter**

(Instead of "nesting" NavigationView inside of ContentPanel.)

- Copy Maui sources ContentViewHandler.cs and ContentViewHandler.Windows.cs, to MyContent... files.
- Replace "ContentView" with "MyContentView" and "ContentPanel" with "NavigationView".
- Observe that it won't compile. "CrossPlatformMeasure" and "CrossPlatformArrange" don't exist in "NavigationView".
- Make a new class "NavigationPanel" to adapt "NavigationView". Equivalent of "ContentPanel" which adapts "Panel" for ContentView. Adapt from `Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentPanel` source.
- Where you previously replaced "ContentPanel" with "NavigationView", instead use this new "NavigationPanel".

Comment: Thanks, i will give this a try and let you know.  I think my major issue is that i thought of the item as a control no a content page

Comment: I may have inadvertently led you to think that way more than you should. In my first two approaches, I rely on ContentView mapper and its ability to "wrap" one control. I ONLY do that because it may need less coding than implementing it "as a control" - map directly to NavigationView as in Approach 3. Once there is more info and examples of Maui, Approach 3 might be preferred. I don't know enough yet to write a wrapper or extension class that can more easily "adapt" any platform class such as NavigationView, so that you don't need to write "NavigationPanel" (or it becomes trivial to do so).

Comment: So making progress but now kind of stuck with the NavigationPage.  Using the Winui3 tab view, adding a tabitem its content i wanted to add the NavigationPage(new SomeNewPage());  In my custom control i convert the content to the actual windows frame and apply that to the WinUI3 TabItem.Content.  But nothing seems to show up in the content page.  Any ideas

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to ToolmakerSteve I found out a direction to do it in.

The ControlView must inherit from both View and IContentView,

```
// So the interface would be 
 [ContentProperty("Content")]
public interface IMyControlView : IContentView
{}

// Then the Control must be constructed with 
public partial class MyControlView : View, IContentView, IMyControlView
{

// Then in the view implement the MapContent

public object Content 
        {
            get { return (View)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
        }
// you must also implement PresentedContent
IView? IContentView.PresentedContent => (View)Content;
}
```

Then in your handler do the mapping for Content and expose it as

```
public partial class MyControlViewHandler : ViewHandler<MyControlView, ActualControl>, IMyControlViewHandler    
{
        public static void MapContent(IZtNavigationViewHandler handler, IZtNavigationView virtualView)
            {
                //((NavigationView)(viewHandler?.PlatformView)).Content = virtualView.Content;
                _ = handler.PlatformView ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(PlatformView)} should have been set by base class.");
                _ = handler.VirtualView ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(VirtualView)} should have been set by base class.");
                _ = handler.MauiContext ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(MauiContext)} should have been set by base class.");
    
    #if WINDOWS
                if (handler.VirtualView.PresentedContent is IView view)
                    handler.PlatformView.Content = view.ToPlatform(handler.MauiContext);
    #endif
            }
}
```

With this i was able to use the WinUI3 NavigationView with Content from ScrollView, BorderView, ContentView.

More to test but thanks for all the help

Comment: Ah, just found out that you will not need to implement the MapContent in your handler the Contentview takes care of that for you

Comment: Superb! Nice solution.

Comment: OK this got back to this and again i am stuck.  It seems like i can add the tab to the tabview but it will not show until i click on the tab.  It seems like when i use a Maui NavigationPage its always not in sync with what the tab thinks its state is, its like the tab api is taking over the maui page.   I have a sample code at https://github.com/cconner100/MauiDtControls. if you run the sample in windows you can see the tab shows, but until you click on the tab the contents wont show

Comment: IIRC, there are still some Maui bugs where UI doesn't refresh when it should. Sorry, I don't have time this month to look at it (a client of mine has a product release deadline). Strip your github down to the minimum files required to show the problem. Add a new issue at github maui issues, with link to your repo, and link to this StackOverflow Q&A. Then add link here to your new issue, so its easy to find. Thanks!