# Adding rounded corners globally to Entry controls in .NET MAUI

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui, .net-maui

In .NET MAUI, there's a nice way to handle styling of controls globally through the `Styles.xaml` file under `Resources/Styles` folder.

Is there a way to add rounded corners to all `Entry` controls through the `Styles.xaml` file rather than handle it individually in `ContentPage` `XAML` files?

Here's the standard styling, out of the box, for `Entry` controls in a .NET MAUI app. Is there a way to add rounded corners to this here? I understand we now handle rounded corners through `Border` control. Could I define a border in `Styles.xaml` and then reference it in styles for `Entry` control?

```
<Style TargetType="Entry">
   <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
   <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource FormElementBackground}" />
   <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular"/>
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
   <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}" />
   <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
      <VisualStateGroupList>
         <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
               <VisualState.Setters>
                  <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
               </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
         </VisualStateGroup>
      </VisualStateGroupList>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: One way to achieve it with shared code is creating a custom control, but you should redeclare all the entry properties you need. Otherwise you may want to use [handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize).

Comment: Make your own custom control, and use that. So far, creating maui `handlers` (that do anything more than set a few properties) seems to be [surprisingly involved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72412170/199364). The code I show in question isn't bad - but look at the actual github repo: I had to copy a number of additional files from Maui sources, to re-use Entry's functionality.

Answer (score 6):

This is how you can add border to an `Entry` control. We can use either `Frame` or `Border`. Here I am using `Border`

```
<Border Stroke="pink"
        StrokeThickness="2">
    <Entry
            Placeholder="I am textbox">
    </Entry>
</Border>
```

[image]

If you want to provide shape, rounded corner to a border, add `Border.StrokeShape`

```
<Border Stroke="pink"
        StrokeThickness="2">
    <Border.StrokeShape>
        <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="0,45,45,0" />
    </Border.StrokeShape>
    <Entry
            Placeholder="I am textbox">
    </Entry>
</Border>
```

[image]

If you want to use it globally, create a custom control like `MyEntry`. Add a `ContentView` and reuse it.