# Why I cannot set Color, CornerRadius and Stroke from handler.PlatformView

Tags: .net, maui

I have a CustomEntry, and I would like to have a entry with a border without the underline, for this reason I created an example that I am doing...

**CODE**

The CustomEnty definition:

```
    public class CustomEntry : Entry
    {
     public static BindableProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
         BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CornerRadius), typeof(int), typeof(CustomEntry), 0);

     public static BindableProperty BorderThicknessProperty =
         BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderThickness), typeof(int), typeof(CustomEntry), 0);

          public static BindableProperty PaddingProperty =
          BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Padding), typeof(Thickness), 
    typeof(CustomEntry), new Thickness(5));

     public static BindableProperty BorderColorProperty =
         BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderColor), typeof(Color), 
     typeof(CustomEntry), Color.FromRgba(0, 0, 0, 0));

     public int CornerRadius
     {
         get => (int)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);
         set => SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value);
     }

     public int BorderThickness
     {
         get => (int)GetValue(BorderThicknessProperty);
         set => SetValue(BorderThicknessProperty, value);
     }
     public Color BorderColor
     {
         get => (Color)GetValue(BorderColorProperty);
         set => SetValue(BorderColorProperty, value);
     }
     /// <summary>
     /// This property cannot be changed at runtime in iOS.
     /// </summary>
     public Thickness Padding
     {
         get => (Thickness)GetValue(PaddingProperty);
         set => SetValue(PaddingProperty, value);
     }
 }
```

**XAML**

My page is defined by:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MauiApp.CustomEntry.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MauiApp.CustomEntry.Controls"
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout Padding="30" Spacing="25">
            <controls:CustomEntry
                Padding="20,0,0,0"
                BackgroundColor="White"
                BorderColor="Blue"
                BorderThickness="2"
                CornerRadius="0"
                Placeholder="Insert a text"
                PlaceholderColor="Orange"
                Text="" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

the result is:

[image]

I have the code in MauiProgram:

```
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static Microsoft.Maui.Hosting.MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = Microsoft.Maui.Hosting.MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                });
            
           Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper 
          .AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
            {
          #if ANDROID
              
                if (view is MauiApp.CustomEntry.Controls.CustomEntry)
                {
                    var entry = (MauiApp.CustomEntry.Controls.CustomEntry)view;
                    handler.PlatformView.SetPadding(Convert.ToInt32(entry.Padding.Left), Convert.ToInt32(entry.Padding.Top), Convert.ToInt32(entry.Padding.Right), Convert.ToInt32(entry.Padding.Bottom));

                    var gd = new Android.Graphics.Drawables.GradientDrawable();
                    gd.SetColor(entry.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
                    gd.SetCornerRadius(entry.CornerRadius + 0f);
                    gd.SetStroke(entry.BorderThickness, entry.BorderColor.ToAndroid());
                    handler.PlatformView.SetBackground(gd);
                }

          #elif IOS
                if (view is CustomPaddingEntry)
                {
                    var entry = (CustomPaddingEntry)view;
                    handler.PlatformView.LeftView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, entry.PaddingLeft, 1));
                    handler.PlatformView.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
                    handler.PlatformView.RightView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, entry.PaddingRight, 1));
                    handler.PlatformView.RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
                    //TODO MAUI HANDLER - VERIFY IT
                    handler.PlatformView.BorderStyle = UIKit.UITextBorderStyle.None;
                }
            #endif
            });

                return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}
```

But in Android it does not works, and this code is from my Render in Xamarin App.

Why this not works?

Comment: Where do you execute this code? Do you use AppendToMapping or something else? I think some more code would be useful here

Comment: I execute the code in MainProgram, and I am using AppendToMapping, just add more code

Answer (score 0):

To remove the underline on the android, you can add the following code into class `MauiProgram.cs`:

```
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(Entry), (handler, view) =>
        {
#if ANDROID
            handler.PlatformView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
#endif
        });
```

And on the windows platform, you can put the following code into the `/Platforms/Windows/App.xaml`:

```
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
        <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThickness">0</Thickness>
        <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThicknessFocused">0</Thickness>
 </maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
```

And there is no underline on the iOS platform.

**Note:**

For more information about how to create custom Entry, you can check thread: [MAUI : Customize an Entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72412170/10308336).

Comment: How I define the entry's border?

Comment: You can refer to thread [Adding rounded corners globally to Entry controls in .NET MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72664172/adding-rounded-corners-globally-to-entry-controls-in-net-maui).

Comment: I know that :) thank you

Comment: Have you resolved your problem? And if my answer is useful for you, could you please mark it as answered so that it will help others who have similar problems? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: SetBackgroundColor not works for me

Comment: I have tested on my android device, it just works properly.   What device are you experiencing this problem on?