# I am not able to display Entry with underline in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, .net-maui

I have worked in Xamarin platform and now learning .NET MAUI. All though lot of similarities I am facing certain issues. I am not able to display an basic entry control on my android device the way .NET MAUI documentation claims. Follow is the code snippet for the entry field.

```
<Entry x:Name="entry" Placeholder="Enter text" TextChanged="entry_TextChanged" Completed="entry_Completed" PlaceholderColor="Black" Margin="10,2,10,2" />
```

And follow is the output I can see on my device.

Please correct me if I need to make any other changes to make it work. I am expecting one underline there. Same output is rendered in android 12 and android 8.1. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72404629/maui-customize-an-entry

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a known issue about this problem in maui.

You can follow it up here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7487 .

Of course ,you can also create a custom Entry, for more details, you can check thread:  [MAUI : Customize an Entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72404629/maui-customize-an-entry) .